# Visual Studio for Windows 8 Developer License Pop Up Issue

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2012

My issue is that when I start Visual Studio on Windows 8 Release Preview and I "agree" to renew my developer license, the Developer Sign In window that pops-up is blank (ie there aren't any login controls). This makes VS unusable, so I tried to uninstall it (can't seem to uninstall it from RP) and download a new copy. When I try to download a new version of VS for Win8 (through Dreamspark), the installer that pops up is also blank.

I'm confused as to what the issue is here? Visual Studio or my Windows 8? Any help would be great!

Comment: I'd start by reinstalling .NET frameworks. Otherwise just start over. Hopefully you're on a virtual machine and have a copy of the fresh OS install...

Answer (score 0):

Try `Show-WindowsDeveloperLicenseRegistration` in Powershell. Reference: [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh974578.aspx#getting_a_developer_license_at_a_command_prompt)